# Laravel - Controller on Controller Dependecy

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller

I have a `Post` model and a `User` model. Furthermore, I have a `PostController` and a `UserController`. Each post view has to be accompanied with its user view that displays the user information. Also, user has its own route and `UserController` allows each user view to be individually.
I would like to make it mandatory in my code to display the user view prior to calling the post view. In other words, `PostController` has a dependency on `UserController`. How can I achieve this?

Comment: which version of laravel u r using?

Comment: I am using Laravel 5

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve your goal in two ways.
First, you can use the view's `include('view_file_name')` to insert that view in the `PostController`'s view. but then you have to initialise the variables in the `PostController` and pass it to the view.

Second, You can `extends` the `UserController`. if you wanted use the variables and functions of `UserController` in the `PostController`.

```
class PostController extends UserController {
}
```

Remember `__construct` of the `UserController` will be called when you call any function of `PostController` if you `extends` the controller.